# DNSmasq on 2 interfaces

Tags: local-area-network, dnsmasq, hostapd

SysInfo:

- ubuntu 18.04
- external access point (with its own internal linux system) => interface ap1, IP: 192.168.13.1
- external access point (USB stick) => interface ap0, IP: 192.168.12.1
- `hostapd` running on ap0
- `dnsmasq` running without being binded to any interface bc I need it to work on both interfaces
- DNS must work on local-network only.

The problem is that when I connect through the `ap1` and type "mydomain.com" on my browser it's not working unless I have the USB stick (ap0) attached and working.

IDK if the issue is with hostapd itself or dnsmasq.

My dnsmasq.conf:

```
localise-queries
resolv-file=/etc/dnsmasq.resolv.conf
no-hosts
addn-hosts=/etc/my.hosts
dhcp-range=192.168.12.20,192.168.12.150,255.255.255.0,12h
dhcp-range=192.168.13.20,192.168.13.150,255.255.255.0,12h
dhcp-option=option:domain-search,local
bind-dynamic
```

The addresses in the my.hosts file are setup like this:

```
<IP>\t<DOMAIN>
```

In that file I have all the addresses for both interfaces 192.168.12.1 and 192.168.13.1)

How do I make it work for both interfaces?

Ask for any extra information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify dnsmasq which interface to use what network. You can do this with below change in your dnsmasq.conf file:

```
dhcp-range=ap0,192.168.12.20,192.168.12.150,255.255.255.0,12h
dhcp-range=ap1,192.168.13.20,192.168.13.150,255.255.255.0,12h
```

or,

```
dhcp-range=interface:ap0,192.168.12.20,192.168.12.150,255.255.255.0,12h
dhcp-range=interface:ap1,192.168.13.20,192.168.13.150,255.255.255.0,12h
```

Comment: The interface: argument has been removed from dnsmasq in 2.63 it seems.